# How to get the dump of last 500 rows of a table from mysql database

Tags: mysql

I am trying to do a mysqldump command to get the last 500 lines from a mysql table. What will be the options to be given in the mysqldump command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean data of last 500 columns?
You should consider using `limit` in that case:

`SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 500;`

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table ORDER BY id DESC limit 500;
```

If you have autoincrement id column, this solution will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code specify the criteria in  `--where="date_created='2013-06-25'" >`

```
mysqldump -u username -ppassword database_name table_name --where="date_created='2013-06-25'" > few_rows_dump.sql
```